# Implementation of GNU Scientific Library?

Tags: numerical-analysis, gsl

Does anyone know a collection of articles or books that describes the implementation of the GNU Scientific Library?

This question is not about using the GSL; it's about how the GSL is implemented, their design decisions / tradeoffs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The GSL design document goes into a lot of detail of design decisions [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/design/gsl-design_toc.html). Of course as open source, for "how the GSL is implemented" you can look at the code [e.g. here](http://www.promotionalpromos.com/mirrors/gnu/gnu/gsl/), which is generally well-written and self-documenting.